# Re-declaring variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-declaration, redeclaration

I found out today (via the hard way) that JavaScript allows this to be done, without generating any errors:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
    /* do some stuff */
    for(var i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
        /* do some more stuff */
    }
}
```

I used the same identifier `i` for both loops by accident.

The JavaScript compiler/interpreter does not produce an error (like Java), and neither does it create a different variable that hides the variable on the outer loop (like C++).  They refer to the same variable, so the outer loop will only be run once!

Why is this so?  Is this behaviour useful in any circumstance at all?

Comment: `Is this behaviour useful in any circumstance at all` - it could be - I just can't think of every single circumstance possible to definitively say so :p

Comment: no it isn't useful at all. it's one of the main issues with the language. however with es6 you can used block scoped varibles `let` and `const`

Comment: @synthet1c Thanks for bringing to attention `let` and `const`.  I didn't know JavaScript hoists variables to the top of the function declaration.  Yuck.  And I thought only VBA was so backward to be doing that.

Comment: @Bernard Note also that placing a `break` statement within inner `for` loop will cause other issues.

Comment: @guest271314 could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Bernard The iteration will return to outer loop, then back to inner loop, without completing either and ultimately never stop repeating the process. That is, until the infinite recursion is stopped with `Task manager`

Comment: @guest271314 I see why that happens now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any use for this.  The ability to do `var i;` twice without any warnings or errors seems to be an imperfection with the language.

As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068757/re-declaring-variables-in-javascript#comment67410931_40068757), the usage of `let` instead of `var` solves this problem.  While `var` is hoisted up to the start of the function body, `let` is only hoisted up to the closest `{`.  `let` isn't supported widely yet, though, so it shouldn't be used just yet if you need to maintain compatibility with older browsers.

Code checking tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) can help to detect such duplicate declaration problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, the first value appears twice and all other values to the max number appears only one time.

So it makes no sense at all, to use this pattern.

The redeclaring is moved to top and used only once for the same variable.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    console.log('outer', i);
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        console.log('inner', i);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I know that my example makes no sense in practice, but it's quite easy to make the mistake of using an existing identifier for a new variable.  I wanted to know, as a language, why JavaScript allows such nonsensical code, which is clearly a programmer's mistake, to work without any warnings or errors.

Comment: the commpiler does noch check for sense. redeclaring a variable does not lead to an error, even `'use strict';` does not lead to an error. i suggest to declare all variavles at top of propgram/function and do not use var statements inside of for loop initialization part.